# Kubuntu - Dolphin panel - clear “Recently Saved”

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin

Could someone help with an update on how to clear the "Recently Saved" items in Dolphin?

It seems to be an old issue, and I have only found very old answers which did not seem to have any effect (Clear recent history, Forget everything, etc).
I am installing Kubuntu on a replacement PC for my wife, and I am hoping that there is a simple answer for a basic PC user.
A simple right-click, clear all option would have been nice for basic users though.

PC Info:

- Kernel           : Linux 5.0.0-37-generic (x86_64)
- Version          : #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019
- C Library        : GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1) 2.27
- Distribution : Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- plasmashell      : 5.12.9

[image: Recent]

Comment: Hi, I know how to hide/unhide this.  I just want to be able to clear it - for example similar to clearing your internet browser history.

Comment: Thanx for the feedback. I also tried the System Settings > Workspace Behavior > Privacy > Clear History, but this does not seem to have any effect, even on my Manjaro KDE installation on a different PC.

Comment: Thanx DK. Will do. Appreciate all the input. I think this question can be closed now.

Comment: Please see https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/76341-Does-the-Privacy-tab-work-for-you?p=433422&viewfull=1#post433422. It also mentions disabling "File Search" but I find that very convenient!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clear "Recent Files" and "Recent Locations" by going to

```
Application Launcher > "History" tab
```

There should be a section for "Applications" and a section for "Documents".

Right-clicking any item in either list should give you an option to "Forget Document" and "Forget All"

This will clear the list in both the Application Launcher, and in the "Recent" panel of Dolphin.

[image]